# How to set a limit on the relationship between data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I have a Player table which has fields like PlayerId, firstname, lastname etc.. and a Teams table with fields such as, TeamId, teamname, etc.. I also have a look up table linking the two tables together by showing which player is on which team. My question is, if I wanted to display to the user the Teams that have not exceeded the 20 Player limit and still have room on the team, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can use count() for counting the umber of player related  to the team and filter that result with minus of 20 ..

Comment: Yes, in the lines that @scaisEdge suggested. Try to refer: joining tables, count() function in SQL.

Comment: Oh, of course count(). Did not even think of that XD, thanks so much. @scaisEdge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show teams with quantity of players not exceeding 20:

```
SELECT t.teamname
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN player_team pt ON
  t.teamid = pt.teamid
GROUP BY t.teamname
HAVING COUNT(pt.playerid) <= 20 -- you probably mean < 20
```

Add information on slots availability:

```
SELECT t.teamname, CONCAT(COUNT(pt.playerid), '/20') AS slots_taken -- if 20 is max
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN player_team pt ON
  t.teamid = pt.teamid
GROUP BY t.teamname
HAVING COUNT(pt.playerid) <= 20 -- you probably mean < 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the below as tables and columns,

```
player_table
------------
playerid
firstname
lastname

.
teams
-----
teamid
teamname

.
player_team_association
------------------------
teamid
playerid
.
```

Your query should look like this

```
select t.teamname, count(pta.playerid) as PlayerLimit,
(20 - PlayerLimit) as AvailableSlots
from teams t,player_team_association  pta
where t.teamid = pta.teamid
group by pta.teamid having PlayerLimit <=20
```

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` as per teames with no players at all

Comment: Yes ... missed this scenaio ... @StormoPM please edit the comment with the left outer join version of the query :)